# How to display Photograph without distortion in Android Application

Tags: android, android-bitmap, bitmapfactory

My current Android Application allows the user to select any photograph they have on their device.

I use this code to display all photographs to allow user selection

```
final Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
```

Once the photograph has been selected, i display it within my applications main activity.

My main activity employs a LinearLayout as follows:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/photograph"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/select_photo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:text="Photo Select" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I use this code to display the photograph in my application

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
            Uri imageUri = data.getData();
            try {
                final Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

The selected photographs are never dislayed correctly, e.g. they are distorted to a lesser or greater degree.

How do i guarantee that any photograph selected is displayed with the correct dimensions/proportions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either size your `ImageView` to "the correct dimensions/proportions", or use `android:scaleType` to indicate how you want the image scaled when it is applied to the `ImageView`.